# How can three-dimensional (mechanical) waves be visualized?

Tags: waves, visualization

I wish to see a visualization of a (mechanical) wave propagating through a medium, e.g. my voice through air when I speak or waves into the depths of a glass of water (or the sea) when I dip my finger in it.

I do not wish for a visualization that shows the pressure or something similar at one point of the affected space depending on time, but an overall image. I imagine this being fairly difficult as we can't see through solid objects, but people can get creative [sometimes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/734790/509159).

---

**My thoughts:** I know how ([surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_wave)) waves on water [look](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Espejo_(3207185886).jpg). One can easily see where the water is higher and lower (crest and trough).

I can also understand how waves can be visualized in two dimensions:

[image: Two waves interference]

Here red can be understood as crest, dark blue as trough and azure as the "normal" state of the medium.

This image is easy enough, as I can replicate it (in poor quality) on water myself. I am aware that there is a fine difference between surface waves and [transversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_wave) waves (as mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_wave)), but as far as I understand, both (the latter in 2D) can be visualized with the image above. I have absolutely no idea how to generalize the image above to three dimensions.

**Side note:** My physical knowledge is, at best, based on school and occasionally reading wikipedia entries.

Comment: You need to find a virtual reality simulation if you actually want to see 3D waves with your eyes.

Comment: @DavidWhite Nowadays this doesn't sound impossible anymore, anyone working on that?

Comment: try searching "3d simulation of waves"

Comment: @annav this mainly gives me 3d simulations of surface waves, which are nice to watch but not what I was asking for. Maybe you had a specific result in mind and could provide a link?

Comment: sorry, no . I was just searching hoping to find something useful